What to do with pretty obviously off-topic questions on the front page
There are a couple of pretty obviously off-topic, almost spammy questions on the front page right now:

My basset hound puppy barked. So I hit him with a skillet. Was this reasonable?
My 1-week old son screamed. So I hit him very hard with a frying pan. Was this reasonable?

What do we do with them? Do we flag them? But given that there are no mods on this site, that seems a bit pointless. How do we get rid of them (or at the very least get them off the front page)?

For absolute nonsense like this definitely flag, but also downvote and vote to close.  There are automatic mechanisms in place (like question block, answer block, question limits, questions with a score of -5 or less don't appear on the front page, and autodeletion) that require this feedback.  This is also useful information for moderators to take action.
But... are there really no moderators here?  It looks like the answer is: yes.  That's problematic; maybe it's time for some pro-tempore moderators to be assigned?

I flagged them as rude/abusive. According to the MSE post, "What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?" four rude/abusive flags will automatically lock and delete a post without any need for a moderator to handle said flags.

Flag so that SE employees can delete the questions faster (Spencer is handling the flags currently), vote to close so that the community can vote to delete once closed, and downvote.
